# How to read XML with tags from a Docx using DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, docx, php-ziparchive

I have this code that read the XML of a Docx file:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($fileName);
$xmlDoc = $zip->getFromName('word/document.xml');
```

Starting from this, how can I modify it using DOMDocument?

My objective is to use a native function of PHP, and if there is something better can you give me an explanation of why use something else instead of DOMDocument.?

**EDIT**

For a better explanation, here is the "complete" code:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open("MyFile.docx");
if (($index = $zip->locateName("word/document.xml")) !== false) {
    $text = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
    $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($text, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
    $xmlText = $xml->saveXML();
}
$zip->close();
```

Now I need to remove some nodes, but the file is modified using PHPWord and it's full of

`<w:t>First text</w:t>
<w:t>Second text</w:t>
<w:t>Third text</w:t>`.

I only need to remove one of these, but I don't know how to catch the one that i need.

Comment: I think it is more a case of what you are intending to extract from the document, sometimes the fact you can read it using DOMDocument doesn't mean it is a viable option.

Comment: I know, that's why I need to know if there is a better alternative. I simply have to read an XML document, remove some nodes and save all the work done, but seems that it won't work with DOMDocument.

Comment: Can you give a fuller piece of code to show what you are trying to do and what isn't working.  There should be no reason why it shouldn't work (as far as I can tell with the minimal details so far).

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the code you have so far, you can see how to find the various pieces of text.  You have to register the namespace w with the new DOMXpath object and then you can search for any element in the document which (in this case) is `<w:t>` using `//w:t`.

This code only loops through them and displays the values, but not sure what you want to do with the content...

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open("text.docx");
if (($index = $zip->locateName("word/document.xml")) !== false) {
    $text = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
    $xml = new DOMDocument();

    $xml->loadXML($text, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
    $xmlText = $xml->saveXML();

    $xp = new DOMXPath($xml);
    // Register main namespace (w)
    $xp->registerNamespace("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

    // Search for <w:t> elements
    $text = $xp->query("//w:t");
    foreach ($text as $entry)   {
        echo $entry->textContent.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
$zip->close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to search some nodes and remove them, but I tried to use preg_replace with some regex on the $xmlText and it works.

Comment: Using regex with XML can be unreliable - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1213708